# Linux changing vimrc theme color with alias

Tags: linux, vim, themes, solarized

I recently started running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.3.6 and I'm really liking it. I managed to install the Solarized theme and I used [sigurdga's gnome-terminal-colors-solarized](https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized) to make the terminal colors work with vim.

Recently I've discovered that I like the dark theme in some situations and the light theme in others, and so I've aliased a command to run the ./solarized executable in sigurdga's repo. However, I've noticed that I have to manually change the .vimrc `set background = light` value between `light` and `dark`. I was wondering if I could alias my `solarize` command to toggle the background value in .vimrc as I toggle the terminal colors?

Alternatively, if you think I have an awful setup please show me how to make it better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use solarized but normally `set background=light` (or dark) should be set in the color scheme it self. There should be no reason to set it manually in your vimrc. (You can also always just add a sed command to change the value from light to dark when you run your solarized script)

Comment: I don't understand your situation well enough to propose a concrete answer, but there are a couple of approaches you can take. One is to have your `~/.vimrc` determine your preferred `'background'` from the environment, assuming that the "situations" you referred to have some differentiable aspect to their environments. Another is to include the `'background'` setting as part of the alias you use in each situation. From the command line, you can set the values of Vim options and you can call functions if simply setting an option isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying you have an awful setup, but I'll show you what I do in case it's useful (this is the same as I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1190190/switch-colorscheme-in-terminal-vim-and-tmux-from-dark-to-light-with-one-command/1640394#1640394)):

I implemented a way to toggle between a light to dark colour scheme for both Vim and Tmux in one go with a simple shortcut (entered into either Vim or Tmux). I use Bash not Zsh though, but hopefully it helps someone. I don't have the rep to show images but I have it [all in a blog post here.](https://matt-a-bennett.github.io/colour_switching_terminal/colour_switching_terminal.html)

In my case I can do either:

From a Tmux pane:
1a) The alias 'ol' switches both Vim and Tmux to light mode.
1b) The alias 'od' switches both Vim and Tmux to dark mode.

From Vim:
2) 'Leader-o' toggles both Vim and Tmux between light and dark colour schemes.

[dark example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ewOt.png)
[light example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q63dQ.png)

The way it works is that I define a Tmux environmental variable that keeps track of whether we have a light or dark colour scheme. Anytime I switch, be it from Vim or a Tmux pane, the variable will be updated. Existing and new Tmux panes and existing and new instances of Vim will check this variable and follow the scheme.

### Code implementation

#### Step 1: Switching from Tmux pane

First, I've configured my ~/.bashrc such that it will automatically launch Tmux and attempt to connect to a session called 'main', or create it if it doesn't exist. I find this works for me, but you may want to alter this step.

Once I've launched Tmux, I query the environment variable called 'THEME', if it's not equal to 'THEME=light' (or just doesn't exist), then we go with the dark theme. This means that when we first launch a Tmux session, we will default to a dark theme:

```
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
    [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && tmux new-session -A -s main

    # check if we have been switched to light, else go dark
    [[ ! $(tmux show-environment | grep THEME) =~ 'THEME=light' ]] && 
    tmux set-environment THEME dark
fi
```

At the beginning of my ~/tmux.conf file, I start by sourcing a secondary Tmux file that contains the dark colours I've chosen. These values may get overridden by a light scheme later:

```
# source colorscheme
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'
source-file ~/.tmux_dark.conf
```

These are the dark theme colours I have:

```
# dark colours
# fg = thin line
set -g pane-border-style "bg=colour234 fg=colour244"
set -g pane-active-border-style "bg=colour234 fg=colour208"
# fg = text
set -g window-style 'fg=colour248,bg=colour234'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour252,bg=colour235'
# Customize the status line
set -g status-fg colour208
set -g status-bg colour234
```

In addition to ~/.tmux_dark.conf, I have ~/.tmux_light.conf:

```
# light colours
# fg = thin line
set -g pane-border-style "bg=colour253 fg=colour244"
set -g pane-active-border-style "bg=colour253 fg=colour208"
# fg = text
set -g window-style 'fg=colour238,bg=colour253'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=colour238,bg=colour231'
# Customize the status line
set -g status-fg colour208
set -g status-bg colour253
```

If I'm in a Tmux pane, and want to switch colour schemes, I just source the relevant file, and update the THEME variable. I have two aliases in my ~/.bashrc to do this. I remember them as ol for 'ON/Light', and od for 'OFF/Dark':

```
# switch between light and dark themes
alias ol="tmux source-file ~/.tmux_light.conf; tmux set-environment THEME 'light'"
alias od="tmux source-file ~/.tmux_dark.conf; tmux set-environment THEME 'dark'"
```

#### Step 2: Switching from Vim

In my ~/.vimrc, I've defined two functions, one to set the colour scheme and another to handle the reading and updating of the Tmux THEME variable. The colour scheme we pick is dictated by the Tmux THEME variable, which we read with a system call to Tmux. This returns the THEME variable, as well as a message saying 'Press ENTER or type a command to continue'. Obviously we're only interested in the variable. If the variable indicates we should be dark, we choose a dark colour scheme (in my case zenburn), otherwise we go with a light one (in my case seoul256-light). Importantly, since I'm checking a match with 'THEME=dark', we must take only the first 10 characters of message returned by the system call:

```
function! SetColorScheme()
    " check if tmux colorsheme is light or dark, and pick for vim accordingly
    if system('tmux show-environment THEME')[0:9] == 'THEME=dark'
        colorscheme zenburn
    else
        colorscheme seoul256-light
    endif
endfunction
```

Toggling the colour scheme between light and dark is done with a call to another function. The function also re-sources the appropriate Tmux colour scheme and updates the THEME variable. Once the THEME variable is updated, we call the SetColorScheme function above to change Vim's colours:

```
function! Toggle_Light_Dark_Colorscheme()
    if system('tmux show-environment THEME')[0:9] == 'THEME=dark'
        :silent :!tmux source-file ~/.tmux_light.conf
        :silent :!tmux set-environment THEME 'light'
    else
        :silent :!tmux source-file ~/.tmux_dark.conf
        :silent :!tmux set-environment THEME 'dark'
    endif
    :call SetColorScheme()
endfunction
```

We can create a mapping (or a command) to quickly toggle the colour scheme like so:

```
nnoremap <Leader>o :call Toggle_Light_Dark_Colorscheme()<cr>
```

When we open a new instance of Vim, the Tmux THEME variable will have already been sent, and so we choose the colour scheme using the SetColorScheme function (note that this must come after the SetColorScheme function in your ~/.vimrc):

```
call SetColorScheme()
```

We could stop there, but in the case where we have an instance of Vim running, and change the scheme using one of our aliases from withing in a Tmux pane, Vim won't automatically re-run the SetColorScheme function.

[toggle in tmux, vim already open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUeoz.png)

We can use an autocmd to check and reset the colour scheme whenever Vim is re-focused. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Vim in the terminal, but luckily there is a plugin that resolves it for us:

```
Plugin 'tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events'
```

This plugin requires the following line in your ~/.tmux.conf (or that you've installed the [tmux-sensible](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible) plugin):

```
set -g focus-events on
```

With one of the above options (I just have the line in my ~/.tmux.conf), we can use the FocusGained event in ~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd FocusGained * :call SetColorScheme()
```

This will mean that as soon as you return to vim from the Tmux pane, Vim's colour scheme will update automatically:

[light example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NzLh.png)

It would probably be easy to coerce Vim to constantly check the Tmux THEME variable, but I only switch from light to dark in the evening (i.e. once a day) so I don't want to make Vim do a million checks in the background for such a rare event:

One last remark is that I opted to change the colour of my command prompt to be visible under both colour schemes. In my ~/.bashrc I put 35m to specify a purple colour in bold font. How these numbers specify a colour is mysterious to me, so I just googled around a bit:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

However, choosing colours in the ~/.tmux.conf file is easy with this code which can be pasted into the terminal to display a colour grid of the 0-255 range:

```
for i in {0..255} ; do \
printf "\x1b[48;5;%sm%3d\e[0m " "$i" "$i"; \
if (( i == 15 )) || (( i > 15 )) && (( (i-15) % 6 == 0 )); then \
printf "\n"; \
fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the explicit setting from your `~/.vimrc` and instead pass it to Vim in your alias definitions, e.g.:

```
$ alias darkvim='vim --cmd "set background=dark"'
```

Similar customizations can be done by setting a variable (`--cmd "let g:myvar = '...'"`) and evaluating it in your `.vimrc`.